# how to add custom html and css to wordpress

Tags: customization, css, html

for eg if i want to add this code from this site https://codepen.io/tamak/pen/ApLcq

html 
Tutorial

### Animated

rollOut

bounce

flash

pulse

rubberBand

swing

shake

tada

wobble

bounceIn

bounceInDown

bounceInLeft

bounceInRight

bounceInUp

bounceOut

bounceOutDown

bounceOutLeft

bounceOutRight

bounceOutUp

fadeIn

fadeInDown

fadeInDownBig

fadeInLeft

fadeInLeftBig

fadeInRight

fadeInRightBig

fadeInUp

fadeInUpBig

fadeOut

fadeOutDown

fadeOutDownBig

fadeOutLeft

fadeOutLeftBig

fadeOutRight

fadeOutRightBig

fadeOutUp

fadeOutUpBig

flipInX

### Click

rollOut

bounce

flash

pulse

rubberBand

swing

shake

tada

wobble

bounceIn

bounceInDown

bounceInLeft

bounceInRight

bounceInUp

bounceOut

bounceOutDown

bounceOutLeft

bounceOutRight

bounceOutUp

fadeIn

fadeInDown

fadeInDownBig

fadeInLeft

fadeInLeftBig

fadeInRight

fadeInRightBig

fadeInUp

fadeInUpBig

fadeOut

fadeOutDown

fadeOutDownBig

fadeOutLeft

fadeOutLeftBig

fadeOutRight

fadeOutRightBig

fadeOutUp

fadeOutUpBig

flipInX

Activate

css
div {
    width: 120px;
    height: 100px; 
    display: block; 
    background: green;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    float:left;
    color: white;
    border-radius:10px;
    }

.animated {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

js
$(document).ready(function() {

animationClick('.rollOut1','rollOut'); 
animationClick('.bounce1','bounce'); 
animationClick('.flash1','flash');
animationClick('.pulse1','pulse');
animationClick('.rubberBand1','rubberBand');
animationClick('.shake1','shake');
  animationClick('.tada1','tada');
  animationClick('.swing1','swing');
  animationClick('.wobble1','wobble');
  animationClick('.bounceIn1','bounceIn');
animationClick('.bounceInDown1','bounceInDown');
animationClick('.bounceInLeft1','bounceInLeft');
animationClick('.bounceInRight1','bounceInRight');
animationClick('.bounceInUp1','bounceInUp');
animationClick('.bounceOut1','bounceOut');
animationClick('.bounceOutDown1','bounceOutDown');
animationClick('.bounceOutLeft1','bounceOutLeft');
animationClick('.bounceOutRight1','bounceOutRight');
animationClick('.bounceOutUp1','bounceOutUp');
animationClick('.fadeIn1','fadeIn');
animationClick('.fadeInDown1','fadeInDown');
animationClick('.fadeInDownBig1','fadeInDownBig');
animationClick('.fadeInLeft1','fadeInLeft');
animationClick('.fadeInLeftBig1','fadeInLeftBig');
animationClick('.fadeInRight1','fadeInRight');
animationClick('.fadeInRightBig1','fadeInRightBig');
animationClick('.fadeInUp1','fadeInUp');
animationClick('.fadeInUpBig1','fadeInUpBig');
animationClick('.fadeOut1','fadeOut');

animationClick('.fadeOutDown1','fadeOutDown');
animationClick('.fadeOutDownBig1','fadeOutDownBig');
animationClick('.fadeOutLeft1','fadeOutLeft');
animationClick('.fadeOutLeftBig1','fadeOutLeftBig');
animationClick('.fadeOutRight1','fadeOutRight');
animationClick('.fadeOutRightBig1','fadeOutRightBig');
animationClick('.fadeOutUp1','fadeOutUp');
animationClick('.fadeOutUpBig1','fadeOutUpBig'); 
animationClick('.flipInX1','flipInX');

function animationHover(element, animation){
  element = $(element);
  element.hover(
    function() {
      element.addClass('animated ' + animation);
    },
    function(){
      //wait for animation to finish before removing classes
      window.setTimeout( function(){
        element.removeClass('animated ' + animation);
      }, 2000);
    }
  );
};

function animationClick(element, animation){
  element = $(element);
  element.click(
    function() {
      element.addClass('animated ' + animation);
      //wait for animation to finish before removing classes
      window.setTimeout( function(){
          element.removeClass('animated ' + animation);
      }, 2000);
    }
  );
};

});

wer and how to add
i hv used codesnippets and custo html css js plugin to do but dont know how to call in wordpress page
i  need multiple times to call this animation

Comment: Are you using a third party page builder like Elementor or the Block editor?

Answer (score 0):

Login to wordpress then Appearance->Theme Editor

Add your CSS to style.css file

and place your Javascript code somewhere in footer.php file with `$` replaced with `jQuery`

and on page edit option place css classes where you want to give css to

Comment: That would do the job, but it's not advisable to put this kind of additions to the styles in the theme's stylesheet if the theme is developed by a third party. Maybe it's a good idea to mention **child themes** in this anwer. Also, we can see that an animation library is used in the shared pen; maybe it's a good idea to mention **how to enqueue a stylesheet** as well. Cheers!

Comment: Furthermore, we're not sure the person has **admin level of access**, maybe you should explore the **HTML Block** as an option.